# Retrieve specific record by term

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get a single record from my database using doctrine. I am unsure how to use the findBy() method.

My current code is below:

```
$token = $em->getRepository('APIBundle:Token')->findBy();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to include an array of what you want the `findBy()` method to use. Please see the below code:

```
$token = $em->getRepository('APIBundle:Token')->findBy(array('string' => $string));
```

Just name the `'string'` part of the code as whatever field you are searching, and replace the `$string` with the variable.

Comment: For single result: `$repository->findOneBy(["param" => $value])` would do best.